# Eclipse Kepler CORBA plugin will not compile IDL files

Tags: eclipse, corba, idl

I have installed the CORBA plugin into Eclipse.  When I select an IDL file and use the "CORBA/Compile CORBA stubs" menu item, I get an Eclipse error log entry “Unhandled event loop exception” due to a “java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openorb/compiler/IdlCompiler” exception from                net.sf.eclipsecorba.openorb.OpenORBCompiler.compile(OpenORBCompiler.java:30)

The “org/openorb/compiler/IdlCompiler” class is in OPENORB_Tools.jar, which is on the CLASSPATH.

How can I get the CORBA plugin and its IDL compiler to find and use this class?

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar errors trying to compile my IDL file, and i tried it from the command line:

```
idlj -fall file.idl
```

And got an error message about declaring a function twice.

```
dpss.idl (line 8):  createPlayerAccount has already been declared.
```

Once I fixed the error, I was able to compile the idl in eclipse with no errors.